# To find time interval between execution of a function and again re execution of the same function in a threaded code

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a threaded code in python i need to find out the time between execution of a function a and again re execution of the same function. How to to do so ??
I have tried to use timeit module but getting wrong results

minimal code is

```
def abc1 ():
  process 
def abc2():
  process 
def abc3:
  process
```

As above there are many functions which are threaded I want to find if function abc1 is executed at time 0 then after how much time abc1 will be executed again

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with the concept of decorators and thread-safety, here is a solution:

```
import time
import threading

# Let us define a list that stores the execution start times
exec_history = []
# Define a lock which allows safe access to this list
list_lock = threading.Lock()

# Define a decorator, which will "log" the execution of its function to the list
def log_func_call(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with list_lock:
            # Note down which function and when it was called.
            # Alternatively, you can also log to a file or terminal, etc.
            exec_history.append((fn, time.time()))  
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

# Decorate whichever method you want to track
@log_func_call
def abc1():
    pass

@log_func_call
def abc2():
    pass
```

The `exec_history` will get updated as and when any function is called, along with its start time. Is this what you are looking for?